# facebook search api details

Tags: wpf, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any facebook api which can be used for searching all the public posts for a search string. I have implemented same application for twitter,now my client want to implement same for facebook.

I made some research and found that facebook made search api limited to some publishers and paid. But there is not any information of pricing or protocol to be followed. 
Can any please help me in getting clear picture regarding this so that I can ask my client to proceed further accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Public Post search is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

What´s limited to some publishers is the Public Feed API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

Comment: Do I have to set up a server?Do I need to have some database also?Is there any link which explains these aspects in detail?

Comment: what do you mean? you can´t set up anything, it´s not possible at all as you can read in my answer. you may just go to one of the publishers directly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights#partners